# How to ask somone to remove a picture from social media that you look bad in

Tags: awkward-situations, canada, social-media

I had gone out with a few friends and one took some pictures of us. I know he took several, but for some reason he put a really bad one of me with 2 other friends on Facebook. (bad in the sense I wasn't looking at the camera and unintentionally making a stupid face). The picture has already received several likes. My name isn't tagged in it, but we have a lot of mutual friends and I just don't want everyone seeing it.

How can I politely ask him to take it down? I'm relatively recent friends with him and being from Japan I get the sense he may be very sensitive to negative feed back.

Does something like the following work?

> You took so many good photos and I'm making a ridiculous face in this
>   one, would you be able to switch it with another photo?

My goal is to have him take the photo down and not offend or put strain on our relationship.

Comment: Welcome to IPS! could you provide a geographical tag? it may help improve the answers and is a useful clarification

Comment: @Loki given other questions I thought asking about phrasing is allowed and I didn't see any specific mention in your link?

Comment: @UltraBobcat [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2209/8077) is a meta question about phrasing requests. I think you can make it on-topic by adding specific goals, and your thoughts why you think your approach will not work. Just today I made a similar edit to a phrasing-request question which was put on hold. Have a look at [my edit](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/13784/revisions), maybe you understand better what I mean.

Comment: @Cashbee here is a meta question about phrasing where the answers say it's on topic https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/lets-close-questions-asking-how-to-word-phrase-something?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @UltraBobcat Interesting, since that meta for a very long time had votes leaning in the other way (phrasing should be off-topic), and the meta Cashbee linked was a follow up on that one (you can see there it has a reference to the other one and states 'we've decided it's off-topic). Which is also why we now state in our help center that such requests (for what to say) are off topic.

Comment: What makes you think your friend is so sensitive to negative feedback? Do you have examples of things they have reacted badly to? This may help us understand the kind of behavior you're trying to avoid here. Usually, questions are best if they include some measure of what was already tried, but since you haven't yet, what makes you think your own suggested approach is likely to fail? What do you want us to improve there?

Comment: @UltraBobcat your edit is a step into the right direction. If you now also include why you think your own suggested approach is likely to fail, then I will vote to reopen this question. (I did this with [my aforementioned edit](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/13784/revisions) too, now, and it is already 1 vote away from getting reopened)